# Java NullPointerException when extending parent class

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm getting `NullPointerException` whith below code.

Parent.java

```
public abstract class Parent {

    public Parent(){
        parentFunc();
    }

    public abstract void parentFunc();
}
```

Child.java

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void parentFunc() {
        list.add("First Item");
    }
}
```

when I create and instance of `Child` like `new Child()` I'm getting `NullPointerException`
Here is my console output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Child.parentFunc(Child.java:8)
    at Parent.<init>(Parent.java:5)
    at Child.<init>(Child.java:3)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

I know that exception occurs because of Child.parentFunc() which called in parent constructor, but I really got confused. So I wonder what is going on

**What is the order of creation;**

1. When list variable is created
2. When constructors are called
3. When functions are created and called which called in constructors

Comment: Parents are constructed first, then children.  The List wasn't created when the function was called, hence the NPE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When list variable is created?

It will be created once constructor of `Child` class runs.

> When constructors are called?

When you try to make an object using `new Child()`, constructor is called for `Child` and it internally calls `super()` which calls the superclass constructor `Parent()`.Note that the very first statement in `Child()` constructor is `super()`.

The system will generate no-arguement constructor for you like this:

```
public child()
{
 super();// calls Parent() constructor.
 //your constructor code after Parent constructor runs
}
```

> When functions are created and called which called in constructors

Clear out a bit what are you trying to ask .

```
Order Of Execution:
```

Parent Constructor->Child Constructor-->List

Answer (score 2):

When parent constructor invoked the function called , You list not initialized and defailu value to the Object `null` is there,

```
 @Override
    public void parentFunc() {
        list.add("First Item");   // list not yet initialized
    }
```

Comment: actucally I know, but I wonder when child constructor is created

Comment: Child constructor is provided by System in your case. And the very first statement in system-provided `Child` constructor called the `super();`

Answer (score 2):

You have an implicit Child() constructor. It calls Parent(), Parent() calls parentFunc() which is called in the sub-class. At that moment your list is still null and you get the NullPointerException (NPE).

See also:

[Java Constructor and Field Initialization Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589828/java-constructor-and-field-initialization-order)

Answer (score 2):

It's usually a bad idea to call abstract methods from a constructor, as you exposed yourself to this kind of problem.