# What will be the output of this code and how?

Tags: java, object, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

**Java code-MySuper class is the parent class and is extended by MySub class.I am creating the object  MySub mySub = new MySub().I thought the output would be "y" but when I tried to run the code it was showing *null* as an output **

```java
class MySuper {
    String strl = "x";

    public MySuper() {
        myMethod();
    }

    void myMethod() {
        System.out.print(strl);
    }
}

class MySub extends MySuper {
    String str2 = "y";

    void myMethod() {
        System.out.print(str2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MySub mySub = new MySub();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should define if the Strings are public or private. you should also give MySub an constructor and inside of the constructor call the super method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Constructor and Field Initialization Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589828/java-constructor-and-field-initialization-order)

Answer (score 2):

The implicit constructor used by `MySub` looks like this:

```java
class MySub extends MySuper {

  String str2;

  MySub() {
    super();
    str2 = "y";
  }

  // rest omitted for brevity
}
```

While inline field initialization is technically moved into the constructor, that's not necessarily important to know in and of itself. The important part is that the super constructor is invoked **before** the subclass's fields are initialized. So, when the super constructor invokes the `myMethod()` method, which is overridden by the subclass, the `str2` field has not yet been assigned a non-default value. This results in your code printing out `null`.

And this is why you should avoid invoking overridable methods in a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Java dynamic method dispatch.

In your example. when you're instancing with the default constructor a `MySub` instance, this implicitly performs a call to the superclass' constructor. Within the superclass' constructor there is a call to `myMethod()` which is declared in `MySuper` and overridden in `MySub`.

Now, even if `myMethod` is being called from the superclass' constructor, which could fool us into thinking that the superclass' version of `myMethod` is being called, this is not what is actually happening.

The instance that is performing all these calls is still a `MySub` instance; therefore the `myMethod` implementation that is being invoked by Java is the closest implementation to `MySub`, i.e. the `myMethod` overridden by `MySub`.

So, if in this case the `myMethod` version that is being invoked in the superclass' constructor is the one overridden by `MySub`, why it's not printing `str2` value? This is because, although method calls are dynamically dispatched, fields are statically dispatched. In Java, only methods can override their base class' methods. Child class' fields can only shadow base class' fields (with the same name). So Java already knows at compile time which fields are being used and **only** at run time which method implementations are being invoked. This means that when you're using a field in a child class, you can be sure that the one you're using is always the one you're referring to.

Getting back to your example, since `myMethod` is being invoked from the superclass' constructor, at this point we're still initializing the parent object, the child class' fields have not been initialized yet, they still contain their default values (the default value for references is null). So, in your dynamically dispatched `myMethod` we are printing the value of the statically dispatched `str2` which is still at null because the child class initialization has not happened yet.

Answer (score -1):

**Minor Mistakes:**

1. *null* output is coming because of extending the *MySuper* class and extending *MySuper* class is not required because the default class object can be created anywhere in a package without extending that.
2. You have not called the method *myMethod()* after creating the object *mySub*.That's why it is not printing the output as *y*.

**Solution**:
Try the code below, it is working smoothly.

```
 class MySuper {
        String strl = "x";
        public MySuper() {
            myMethod();
        }
        void myMethod() {
            System.out.print(strl);
        }
    }
    // class MySub extends MySuper {
        class MySub {
        String str2 = "y";
        void myMethod() {
            System.out.print(str2);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MySub mySub = new MySub();
           // extra line added
            mySub.myMethod();
            MySuper ms=new MySuper();
        }
    }
```